# What is a good way to connect a LED to a PCB?

Tags: led, pcb, connector

I need to connect a 5mm LED to a PCB, but the LED is not supposed to be soldered directly to it, but rather connected using a wire.

I'm going to produce around 500 PCBs, so I need a way to connect them the fastest and more reliable way. Is there a standard way to do it?

The LED doesn't have to be a standard 5mm one. If there are other options I'm open to it

Comment: I’m trying to understand what your actual goal is. You have a LED that needs to be connected to the PCB, but you don’t want to solder it directly in to the PCB? Is there a specific reason for this? Placement of the LED in an enclosure? How far away do you need the LED to be? You could have the LED on the PCB and use a light guide instead. You could have a dedicated very small PCB just for the LED, with connectors on both PCBs to wire them together. There are probably other options, but all really depends on your actual goal. Also, is this a single colour LED, or something more advanced?

Comment: are you certain that you understand the requirement? ... what is the exact wording of the requirement? ... there is a difference between `not supposed to be soldered to it` and `not supposed to be soldered directly to it`

Answer (score 2):

Use a 2-pin molex connector pair similar to this. One of the pieces gets soldered into the board, the LED is soldered at the end of the wires.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Abdullah, is there a connector similar to this one but for the LED? To avoid led soldering?

Comment: You can try a "female header". The LED will just insert into it, not soldered.

Answer (score 1):

> *What is a good way to connect a LED to a PCB?*

Use a ZIF (zero insertion force socket). Pull the handle to release the contact clamps, put the LED in and push the handle back to clamp the LED pins.

[image]

Comment: They seem a bit expensive.

Comment: @user253751 where did you source it from? Link please.

Comment: He needs to connect one LED per board. I guess a ZIF socket would be a serious overkill. A 2-pin female header would be good option though.